# change model of textfield from an attribute directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a text field with an attribute directive `tsAutocomplete`:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="street" [tsAutocomplete] />
```

How can I change street **model** of `formControlName="street"` from this `tsAutcomplete` directive?

Here you can see my actual code: https://gist.github.com/istiti/225c29afee646da66224b3388c9b52d9#file-autocomplete-directive-ts-L53

`this._element.nativeElement.value = value;` is not updating model only value of my textfield changed but not model !

Comment: What do you mean by model?

Comment: <input type="text" formControlName="street" [tsAutocomplete] /> You dont have any model binding here

Comment: is `formControl value` changing?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat https://gist.github.com/istiti/e3d9a84ef10a424c6c138d1b4f4bf3f4 I use formBuilder

Comment: So you man form.getRawValue() is not updated?

Comment: Because i am a bit confused on first gist there was no form, now you have form. Can you please post working example where its failing? because on the first example problem was that you dont have any form

Comment: I don't have form because I write it in this question. I have this second url I sent you. here is where I use my tsAutcomplete ! You only need to focus on my directive. So I want this behavior: everywhere I attach my `tsAutocomplete` on a textfield I want change the model inside this directive... model = 2 way binding, in tempalte and in component